# How to overlay footer over background

Tags: css, opencart

I am in the process of build a layout and need the footer to appear as the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V56Hd.png

Currently, the footer just sits inside of the background, while I need it inside of the white area then on top of the footer background as shown:

Here is the code I have on the footer:

```
<footer id="footer">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="column span2">
                        <h3 class="header"><?php echo $text_information; ?> <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></h3>
                        <ul class="content">
                            <?php $i=1; foreach ($informations as $information) { ?>
                            <li id="inf<?php echo $i;?>"><a href="<?php echo $information['href']; ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php $i++; } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="column span2">
                        <h3 class="header"><?php echo $text_service; ?> <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></h3>
                        <ul class="content">
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $return; ?>"><?php echo $text_return; ?></a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $sitemap; ?>"><?php echo $text_sitemap; ?></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!--<div class="column span2">
                        <h3 class="header"><?php echo $text_extra; ?> <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></h3>
                            <ul class="content">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $voucher; ?>"><?php echo $text_voucher; ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $affiliate; ?>"><?php echo $text_affiliate; ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $special; ?>"><?php echo $text_special; ?></a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>-->

                    <div class="column span2">
                        <h3 class="header"><?php echo $text_account; ?> <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></h3>
                            <ul class="content">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
                                <li class="wishlist-link"><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $newsletter; ?>"><?php echo $text_newsletter; ?></a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>



                    <div class="span4">
                        <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_status')== 1) { ?>

                            <div class="social">

                                <h3><?php echo $this->language->get('text_keep_in_touch'); ?></h3>

                                <?php if(($this->config->get('clearshop_facebook_page') != '') && ($this->config->get('clearshop_facebook_icon') == 1)) { ?>
                                    <a href="https://facebook.com/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_facebook_page'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-facebook-sign"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if(($this->config->get('clearshop_twitter_username') != '') && ($this->config->get('clearshop_twitter_icon') == 1)) { ?>
                                    <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_twitter_username'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_youtube_username') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="https://youtube.com/user/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_youtube_username'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-youtube"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_gplus_id') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_gplus_id'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-google-plus"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_pinterest_id') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="https://pinterest.com/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_pinterest_id'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-pinterest"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_instagram_username') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="https://instagram.com/<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_instagram_username'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_tumblr_username') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="http://<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_tumblr_username'); ?>.tumblr.com" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-tumblr"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_skype_username') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="skype:<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_skype_username'); ?>?call" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-skype"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_linkedin_username') != '') { ?>
                                    <a href="linkedin:<?php echo $this->config->get('clearshop_linkedin_username'); ?>?call" target="_blank">
                                        <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>

                            </div>

                            <?php if($this->config->get('clearshop_footer_info_text') != '') { ?>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <?php echo html_entity_decode($this->config->get('clearshop_footer_info_text'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
                                </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>

                </div> <!-- .row-fluid -->

            </div> <!-- .container -->

        </footer> <!-- #footer -->
```

Comment: Can we get just the HTML output, rather than the PHP code?  Also there's no CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you could try is z-index go to css file and write down

```
#footer{z-index:9999;}
```

and see if that works for you, your question is not clear enough, but this was what i understood.